# How to click through a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-view

First of all I am struggling with this issue for a long time. I don't know how to figure out things, so I followed these steps and tutorials with no luck.

1. [Click through recycler view empty space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396075/click-through-recyclerview-empty-space)
2. [Click through a recyclerview list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066594/click-through-a-recyclerview-list-item)

and a bunch of questions on StackOverflow. I wrote my own code also. May be I am doing something silly but am not able to figure it out.

```
mRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
    RectF rectf = new RectF((int) event.getX(), 
                            (int) event.getY(), 
                            0, 0);
    boolean contains = getCenter(mHeaderPopUp).contains(rectf);
    if (contains) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
});

private RectF getCenter(View view) {
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    view.getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
    RectF dimens = new RectF((rect.left + rect.width() / 2), 
                             (int) (rect.top + rect.height() / 2),
                             0, 0);
    return dimens;
}
```

So now I have tried all of these things but I am not able to click through recyclerview to the view which is below recyclerview which you can see in the below image. recyclerview overlays all the views on the screen and I need to pass the click to below recyclerview I don't want to put those views above the recyclerview as when you scroll recyclerview it will be animatated and would cover all the views with its items.
Thanks in advance.
[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vmiH.jpg)

Comment: Put both in a RelativeLayout and define a top margin for your RecyclerView. Then the image above the RecyclerView is clickable

Comment: you didn't get my question i guess

Answer (score 7):

I think I found it.

Use `recycler.setLayoutFrozen(true);`

You can still assign onClickListeners to your items, but if you don't, the click will go through.

From the source code of `RecyclerView.java`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    if (mLayoutFrozen || mIgnoreMotionEventTillDown) {
        return false; // <= This will prevent the RecyclerView from getting the MotionEvent
    }
...
}
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#2795

Comment: after `recycler.setLayoutFrozen(true)`, recyclerView can't scroll. It's terrible

Comment: in my case i dont need it to scroll. thanks alot. my recyclerview was sitting ontop of another one and i wanted it to ignore clicks. this worked.

Answer (score 4):

Hello I found an answer.
I have card below RecyclerView and recyclerView has padding from left and I set clipToFading=false.
To make card below recyclerView clickable I created RecyclerTouch event class and when clicked childView is null it means it is outside childs and open space and I give touch event to my card. 
Here is Code

```
public class RecyclerTouchEvent implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchEvent(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

                return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                super.onLongPress(e);
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        final View childView = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());


        if (childView != null && clickListener != null) {
            clickListener.onClick(childView);
        }else if (childView==null&&clickListener!=null){
            clickListener.onOutsideClick(e);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}

public static interface ClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view);
    public void onOutsideClick(MotionEvent event);
}
```

AND

```
recyclerViewLends.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchEvent(getContext(), recyclerViewLends, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onOutsideClick(MotionEvent e) {
                rippleLayoutAddLend.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
            }
        }));
```

rippleLayoutAddLend is a View below recyclerView that has to be clicked

Comment: There is a lot of unnecessary code, but the solution is correct!

Answer (score 0):

I had situation when my `RecyclerView` header item is fully transparent and need catch click behind it.

Inside `Activity` function:

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean
```

I call extension function `RecyclerView.suppressOnHeader`:

```
/**
 * If [onView] returns true -> it means what need skip this touch action for [RecyclerView]:
 * - Set true for [RecyclerView.suppressLayout], that makes list not scrollable and 
 *   transparent for clicking.
 *
 * If [onView] returns false -> it means what need vice versa make [RecyclerView] 
 * scrollable  and not transparent for clicking:
 * - Set false for [RecyclerView.suppressLayout], turn on touch events and scrolling for list.
 * - Need call [RecyclerView.onInterceptTouchEvent], this need for reset key
 *   [RecyclerView.mIgnoreMotionEventTillDown], which was setup when we call
 *   [RecyclerView.suppressLayout]. If skip this step when first [RecyclerView] click
 *   will be ignored. For information see [RecyclerView.onTouchEvent].
 * - And in the end call [RecyclerView.onTouchEvent], like we make a touch event.
 */
fun RecyclerView.suppressOnHeader(ev: MotionEvent?) {
    if (ev?.action != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return

    val holderView = findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0)?.itemView

    if (ev.onView(holderView)) {
        if (!isLayoutSuppressed) {
           suppressLayout(true)
        }
    } else {
        if (isLayoutSuppressed) {
            suppressLayout(false)
            onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
            onTouchEvent(ev)
        }
    }
}

fun MotionEvent?.onView(view: View?): Boolean {
    if (view == null || this == null) return false

    return Rect().apply {
        view.getGlobalVisibleRect(this)
    }.contains(rawX.toInt(), rawY.toInt())
}
```